# How to find a query that is use deprecated option?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4

Mongodb writes logs

> 2018-04-05T11:38:28.178+0000 W COMMAND  [conn107] Use of the aggregate
>   command without the 'cursor' option is deprecated. See
>   http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/aggregate-without-cursor-deprecation.

How to find related query?

Answer (score 1):

You need go thru your source code! Search all aggregate commands and add needed `,{cursor:{}}` section. Check [here!](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/)

Comment: This is obvious, but we have a lot of applications with different ORM`s. 
Is it possible to increase the details of logging?

Comment: Yes, but with a performance hit. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/  db.setProfilingLevel(0, -1) will write all queries to mongod.log file for that DB.

Comment: Other solution is change verbosity level: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/index.html#log-messages-configure-verbosity

Answer (score 0):

As per MongoDB BOL [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/)

Mongodb 3.4 deprecates the following commands and [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell methods:

**group**

[`group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/group/#dbcmd.group) command and [`db.collection.group()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.group/#db.collection.group). Use [`db.collection.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) or [`db.collection.mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce) instead.

**aggregate without cursor**

MongoDB 3.4 deprecates the use of [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) command without the cursor option, unless the pipeline includes the explain option. When returning aggregation results inline using the [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate) command, specify the cursor option using the default batch size `cursor: {}` or specify the batch size in the cursor option `cursor: { batchSize: <num> }`.